# Firestore max. number of collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this is my first time using Firestore and I am confused about the limit number of collections that I can create. Is there a limit?

-I need suggestions for another thing as well. I am building an app that will require different tables in the database such as Restaurants, Clients and Reservations. In Firestore there are no tables since it is a non-SQL DB, so does a 'Collection' serve as a 'Table'? What about 'Document'?

Comment: What is it that's made you decide to use Firestore? It SOUNDS like from your description that your data is relational. A reservation will have a client ID and a restaurant ID and probably a time column. That's quite relational. Have you thought about just using Cloud SQL instead of Firestore?

Comment: @GabeWeiss dont you think I can still use Firestore? I mean I can still create client ID and restaurant ID there.

Comment: Oh you can, absolutely. It just depends on what you want to do with the data. E.g. are you going to want to be able to retrieve, say, all reservations at a specific restaurant? What kind of latency are you tolerant for? How many records are we talkin? I mean, if you have like, fewer than tens of thousands of records, it really doesn't matter. But if you think you'll grow to higher numbers, picking SQL vs. NoSQL now will matter so you don't have to migrate later. The data you're talking about SOUNDS more relational to me than NoSQL in terms of retrieving the data.

Comment: @GabeWeiss ok so if there will be let's say around 30,000 records in the whole Firestore database, will that be a problem? What kind of problem, slower retrieve?

Comment: Nah, at 30k, you could use almost anything and it won't make a big difference. The difference is just fundamentally between NoSQL and SQL. When you're retrieving records by index, like, for example, fetching all reservations by restaurant ID, SQL is going to be faster. But at 30k records, the difference in time it takes to fetch what you need isn't going to be that big. Firestore is fine.

Comment: @GabeWeiss thanks for the suggestions. btw I checked Cloud SQL pricing and it looks a bit expensive to me. However, if I want to change form Firestore to an SQL DB what else can you suggest? Any idea about Realm DB?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Realm DB, no.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) doesn't say anything about maximum number of collections.  They are essentially just containers for documents, so there is no practical limit that you should be concerned about.

A SQL table is roughly analogous to a Cloud Firestore collection.  A SQL row is roughly analogous to a document.  It's advisable to think of Cloud Firestore not in terms of what you know in SQL, but [on its own terms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model).

Comment: So do you suggest me to create a new collection for each registered 'Client' and each 'Restaurant'? Or should I create just one collection 'Restaurant' and one 'Client' and then for each client and restaurant add a new document?